# CSV deleting first rows using java

Tags: java, csv

I have to set up a java  truck application whose converting a CSV file from GPS to a shapefile and i have to delete the first rows whose speed are less than 5, but once speed is more than 5 the function should stop and the points will be added normally.

Here is part of my code when the points are parsed, added and converted to a shapefile but I'm still wondering how I can delete just the first rows until speed is higher than 5 ...

```
    for (line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
        if (line.trim().length() > 0) { // skip blank lines
            String tokens[] = line.split("\\,");
            String name1 = tokens[0].trim();
            String name2 = tokens[1].trim();
            double latitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);
            double longitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]);
            String name = tokens[4].trim();
            String name4 = tokens[5].trim();

            /* Longitude (= x coord) first ! */
            Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude));

            featureBuilder.add(point);
            featureBuilder.add(name1);
            featureBuilder.add(name2);
            featureBuilder.add(name);
            featureBuilder.add(name4);
            SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);
            features.add(feature);
        }
    }
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: Looks like your keyboard is on the fritz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - if tokens[5] is speed, you likely need to parse it from a String to a number, e.g. Integer.parseInt(tokens[5]), or Float.parseFloat(tokens[5]).  Then you can skip lines like you did for blanks, this time only when the speed is less than 5. And if you only want to skip the first lines below 5, you can keep a flag for foundAnyRowHigherThan5.  See an example below:

```
    boolean foundAnyRowHigherThan5 = false;
    for (line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
        if (line.trim().length() > 0) { // skip blank lines
            String tokens[] = line.split("\\,");
            String name1 = tokens[0].trim();
            String name2 = tokens[1].trim();
            double latitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);
            double longitude = Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]);
            String name = tokens[4].trim();

            String speedString = tokens[5].trim();
            float speedFloat = Float.parseFloat(speedString);

          if(foundAnyRowHigherThan5 || speedFloat > 5.0) {
            // from this point forward, you will not skip lines based on speed.
            if(!foundAnyRowHigherThan5) {
              foundAnyRowHigherThan5 = true;
            }

            /* Longitude (= x coord) first ! */
            Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude));

            featureBuilder.add(point);
            featureBuilder.add(name1);
            featureBuilder.add(name2);
            featureBuilder.add(name);
            featureBuilder.add(name4);
            SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);
            features.add(feature);
          }
       }
    }
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: thak you marc @marc   thaaat works very well and all first lines  are deleted   thaank you foor you r help  ..... u saved my life